# My theme is not showing up on any other computers

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve

I have Wordpress installed to mydomain.org/blog, and everything works fine and dandy from my computer (localhost). However, when I connect to the blog from another computer, the theme (Twenty Twelve) disappears and it's all plaintext. I have not tried to install any other themes. Help?

Edit: URL upon request is http://boj.cc/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had done was in the WordPress Admin page, under Settings > General, I had put `localhost/blog` for the `WordPress Address (URL)`. Changing this to the public URL of my site fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting the files on localhost it means that your files are stored ONLY on the computer you're building the site on. If that's the case, you need to purchase hosting from a company like bluehost or hostgator or godaddy etc etc. Once you purchase a hosting account and connect it to your domain name, you then need to upload or install Wordpress onto the server associated with your hosting account.

There are literately billions of places to find info on this topic via Google. If you do a little searching around you can easily find a step-by-step guide on how to do the above.

Comment: No, I am hosting a website. The website works fine. I am just hosting it from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

All your theme URLs point to `http://localhost`. I guess you have hard-coded the URLs.

- Use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) for your scripts and stylesheets.
- Use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to get the current theme URL, not a hard-coded URL. In child themes use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Comment: I don't recall hard coding the URLs. I'm kinda new to WordPress, how would I fix this?